# Android saving a variable when activity destroyed then recreated

Tags: timer, savestate

I'm creating an app that has a button controlling a countDownTimer that runs regardless of whether the app is open or not. At the end of the timer a notification pops up in status bar prompting the user to start another activity. This timer repeats at increasing intervals for x amount of times. Also, to prevent the user from accidentally starting the timer multiple times I disable the button after the first press. At the end of the countdown repetition cycle the button re-enables.

All of that works fine when I keep the activity open...

My problem is when I press BACK. If I reopen the activity, the button fails to re-enable after the countdown cycle ends. I believe that the state of variable "count" is lost when the activity is destroyed.

I'm quite new to programming and would appreciate any assistance. I apologize for how messy this code is! It's still very much a work in progress. Thanks in advance!

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    startB.setOnClickListener(this);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(times[count], interval);
    LoadPreferences();
    if (savedInstanceState !=null)
    {
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("mCount");
    }
    else
    {
        count=0;
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    savedInstanceState.putInt("mCount", count);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    SavePreferences();

    super.onBackPressed();
}

private void SavePreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
    editor.putBoolean("state", startB.isEnabled());
    editor.commit();
}

private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int mCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", mCount);
    Boolean state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state",true);
    startB.setEnabled(state);
    mCount = count
}




            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (!timerHasStarted)
                        {
                            countDownTimer.start();
                            timerHasStarted = true;
                            Toast t= Toast.makeText(this,"Timer Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            startB.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                }

            // CountDownTimer class
            public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
                {

                    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
                        {
                            super(startTime, interval);
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish()
                        {

                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("ASL Teacher")
                        .setContentText("Play Lesson One");
                        //Intent resultIntent= new Intent();
                        //TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
                        //stackBuilder.addParentStack(NextActivity.class);
                        //stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        //PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


                        Vibrator v= (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(pattern,-1);
```

//                          Toast t= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Times Up "+String.valueOf(times[count]),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 //                             t.show();
                            count++;

```
                        if (count < 3)
                        {

                            countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(times[count], interval);
                            countDownTimer.start();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        count=0;
                            startB.setEnabled(true);
                            timerHasStarted=false;

                        }


                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question is still relevant.

You should check where the variable mCount appears. When you LoadPreferences, you read "mCount" into mCount, using the its undefined value as default. Then you drop the read value by doing mCount=count. Did you mean count=mCount?

After LoadPreferences in onCreate, you set count only according to savedInstanceState. So whatever LoadPreferences does to count is ignored. When the activity is started after you have killed it by pressing BACK, the savedInstanceState will be null but you won't want count to be 0 if preferences say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this use cancel method of count down timer and save the time remaining then in the on resume method of activity start a new count down timer